# Xamarin.iOS Linker Behavior Conflicting .NET Library

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Since Apple announcing uses of `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`, Microsoft has official shared a "trick" to manage this issue on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809

The document said that to select `Link All` of `SDK Only` on Linker Behavior setting and add additional "mtouch arguments" as `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type`. It seem now Xamarin is running the app using `WKWebView` and apple store has accepted it.

But changing the Linker Behavior seems create another issues, it turn out the `Newtonsoft.Json` library  is not working properly. If I turn it `Don't Link`, then the app is working properly.

Is there anyway to implement `WKWebView` programmatically without changing the Linker Behavior?

Comment: You can remain `SDK Only` option  and skip `Newtonsoft.json` in additional mtouch args , check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67907/json-deserialize-fails-when-linker-is-set-to-link-all

Comment: I dont think its a good solution. The `Newtonsoft.Json` library now can be use, but then `ToString` method now not working.